# What if an answer is edited after it has been flagged? I can't change my flag, but now the flag is not needed

Tags: support, flagging, flag-weight

I flagged an answer as "Not an answer" that at the time was a one sentence comment on another answer. Since that time the answer has been totally rewritten: none of the original sentence is there in the form it existed at the time, and much new content has been added. A comment by another user has also been deleted that informed the original author of the shortcomings of his answer. Especially since the edit history is not accessible from the 'Tools' screen that shows questions/answers that have been flagged by other users, the flags I and 3 other users placed in the answer have subsequently been marked as 'deemed invalid' by two additional users. The answer in question:

https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46195/15871

My question here: In such a situation, are the original flags placed by myself and three others when the flags were valid considered 'helpful' or do they negatively impact our "flag weight" if the needed changes are made before a moderator looks at the flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag weight is gone, so don't worry too much on that front. If you want to notify us that the cause of the flag has been corrected, chat or meta is a good way to go. :)

Comment: So basically just post a question here to the effect: I flagged this answer (http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46195/15871) that has since been edited rendering the flag invalid?

Comment: Yep, or use chat. Either is fine.